# It does not show "this" objects in object oriented JavaScript inside Console

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am following Object Oriented JavaScript tutorial and I am having an issue when I console log "userOne.login", expecting to see "ryu@ninjas.com has logged in" but ended up seeing

"ƒ login(){console.log(this.email, 'has logged in');
  }"

Which seems like "this" is not picking up the email. I would like to know why I am getting this message. Thank you.

```js
var userOne = {
  email:'ryu@ninjas.com',
  name:'Ryu',
  login(){
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged in');
  },
  logout(){
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged out');
  }
};
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Object Oriented JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Object Oriented JavaScript</h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is fairly quick fix just add `()` to the end of your function call. for example `login()`. `login` references the definition of the function which is actually an object that is linked to the prototype `Function`. The way to run the function as a body of functionality is to invoke it with the parens.

Comment: Thank you for an additional explanation. Wasn't paying attention haha

Comment: No worries! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
var userOne = {
  email:'ryu@ninjas.com',
  name:'Ryu',
  login: function(){
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged in');
  },
  logout: function(){
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged out');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is slightly off; you need to give the functions a key within your object, such as `login: function()` and `logout: function()`. Then you can invoke these functions with `userOne.login()` and `userOne.logout()`:

```js
var userOne = {
  email: 'ryu@ninjas.com',
  name: 'Ryu',
  login: function() {
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged in');
  },
  logout: function() {
    console.log(this.email, 'has logged out');
  }
};

userOne.login();
userOne.logout();
```

```html
<h1>Object Oriented JavaScript</h1>
```

Note that storing functions within their corresponding objects is the preferred approach, as these functions are contained within the scope of the object, and do not pollute the global scope; you cannot simply call `login()`.

Comment: Thank you. The author was using an ES6, thus he skipped function();